# Change AWS S3 File Path naming convetion Django Storage

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

A S3 Bucket URL format of a bucket is either of below two options:

1. [http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket_name]/](http://s3.amazonaws.com/%5Bbucket_name%5D/)
2. http://[bucket_name].s3.amazonaws.com/

I am using django storages to store files in S3.
When I am fetching files in one of my deployment the s3 url format is like number 1 in above list and in other deployment it is of format 2.

I checked all the settings, but everything seems to be same. Is there a way to set this convention or any way to keep this consistent.

Comment: What are your settings and what are versions of django-storages are you running? Something must differ between them to see that difference

Comment: Django==3.0.3
django-storages==1.9.1

Comment: same at both places